# Distribution of $|q|^2$ if $\Re[q]\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma^2/2)$ and $\Im[q]\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma^2/2)$

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable

Let $q$ be a complex random variable such that:

$\Re[q]\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma^2/2)$ and $\Im[q]\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma^2/2)$.

What is the PDF and CDF of the squared norm  $|q|^2$ ?

Comment: Since $|q|^2 = \mathbb{R}(q)^2 + \mathbb{I}(q)^2$, this really has nothing to do with complex random variables: it asks for the distribution of the sum of squares of two Normal variables having a common variance. There is no unique answer without the additional assumption that the real and imaginary parts are *independent*, in which case I'm sure a little research will identify answers in several places on this site.  The Wikipedia article on the [non-central chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) gives a fuller account.

Comment: @whuber Actually, the only thing that complex random variables contribute to the issue is that a commonly used definition of a complex Gaussian random variable $\mathcal CN(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is a pair $(X,Y)$ of _independent_ Gaussian random variables with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ respectively, and the same variance $\sigma^2/2$. At least, that is usually the case in communications systems theory, information theory, and the like, which fields I am more familiar with than statistics, and so I immediately assumed that this common definition is what the OP intended when I read the question.

Comment: @Dilip Thank you for the clarification.  One reason I commented is that this question does *not* state that $q$ is a complex *Gaussian* random variable: it only states that $q$ is a (generic) complex-valued random variable whose real and imaginary parts are, separately, real Gaussian variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $$|q|^2=\Re[q]^2+\Im[q]^2.$$ Note (assuming independence) $$\frac{2}{\sigma^2}|q|^2=\frac{2}{\sigma^2}\Re[q]^2+\frac{2}{\sigma^2}\Im[q]^2\sim\chi_2^2\left(\frac{2}{\sigma^2}(\mu_1^2+\mu_2^2)\right).$$ Hence, $|q|^2$ has scaled [non-central chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution), which unfortunately does not have nice cdf and pdf. However, since the characteristic function is available as $$\varphi(t)=\frac{1}{(1-i\sigma^2t)}\exp\left(\frac{i(\mu_1^2+\mu_2^2)t}{1-i\sigma^2t}\right),$$ it is possible to recover pdf and cdf numerically through inverse Fourier transform and Gil-Pelaez theorem, respectively.

Comment: I think there is something missing in the distribution. The multiplication by a constant scales the variance and the mean, so $\frac{2}{\sigma^2}|q|^2=\frac{2}{\sigma^2}\Re[q]^2+\frac{2}{\sigma^2}\Im[q]^2 \sim \chi_2^2(\frac{2}{\sigma^2}(\mu_1^2+\mu_2^2) )$. Am I  right ?

Comment: @din: You are correct. After scaling $\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sigma}\Re[q]\sim N\left(\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sigma}\mu_1,1\right)$, and $\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sigma}\Im[q]\sim N\left(\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sigma}\mu_2,1\right)$. Thus $\lambda=\dfrac{2}{\sigma^2}(\mu_1^2+\mu_2^2)$. I have changed my answer.